# How do we edit the FAQ

Tags: discussion, support

we have a number of questions to add to the official FAQ for this site. How do we edit it ?

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question on meta.SO today and don't have an answer yet:

[Updating the FAQ for a StackExchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61996/updating-the-faq-for-a-stackexchange-site)